# Java Constructor not being defined

Tags: java, constructor

Java constructor not working.

I need to make three constructors and a print method. Then make three objects and print them. Please forgive me if the problem I wrote in the title is wrong. I have close to no idea what is going on with my code. But here it is. Can anybody tell me what is wrong with it and how I  can fix it.

```
/** class Student
 * with 4 instance variables,
 * 3 constructors, a print method,
 * and a main method to test them.
 */
 public class Minor
 {
     // Write 4 instance variables
     private int id;
     private int age;
     private double height;
     private boolean goodVictim;
     

     // Write 3 constructors to initialize the instance variables
     //  1. no parameters using default values
     public Minor() {
         id = 0;
         age = 11;
         height = 5;
         goodVictim = true;
     }
     //  2. 1 parameter and the rest default values
     public Minor(boolean initGoodVictim) {
         goodVictim = initGoodVictim;
     }
     //  3. 4 parameters
     public Minor(int initid, int initAge, double initHeight, boolean initGoodVictim) {
         id = initid;
         age = initAge;
         height = initHeight;
         goodVictim = initGoodVictim;
     }


     // Write a print method that prints all the instance variables
     public void print()
     {
         System.out.println(id);
         System.out.println(age);
         System.out.println(height);
         System.out.println(goodVictim);
     }

    // main method
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       // Construct 3 Minor objects using the 3 different constructors
        Minor minor1 = new Minor(4012010, 12, 5.0, true);
        Minor minor2 = new Minor(30112004, 17, 6.2, false);
        Minor minor3 = new Minor(12052008, 14, 5.5, true);


       // call their print() methods
        print(minor1);
        print(minor2);
        print(minor3);

    }
 }
```

here is the error:
Minor.java:51: error: no suitable constructor found for Minor(int,int,int,int,boolean)
Minor minor3 = new Minor(12052008, 14, 5,5, true);
^
constructor Minor.Minor() is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor Minor.Minor(boolean) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor Minor.Minor(int,int,double,boolean) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
Minor.java:55: error: method print in class Minor cannot be applied to given types;
print(minor1);
^
required: no arguments
found:    Minor
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
Minor.java:56: error: method print in class Minor cannot be applied to given types;
print(minor2);
^
required: no arguments
found:    Minor
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
Minor.java:57: error: method print in class Minor cannot be applied to given types;
print(minor3);
^
required: no arguments
found:    Minor
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
4 errors

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: "Construct 3 Minor objects using the 3 different constructors" <- Your 3 Constructors take 1. No argument 2. A single boolean argument and 3. 2 int, 1 double and 1 boolean - Yet the 3 constructor calls you try have little to do with calling your 3 different constructors. You never call the no argument constructor or the constructor that only takes a boolean.

Comment: Note that `04012010` isn't the number 4012010. Don't have leading zeroes - that means javac interprets the number as octal.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in the creation of `minor3`. The third parameter needs to be a `double`, but you are providing `5,5`. That's not a double but 2 different parameters.

In the creation of `minor2` you are providing a correct double literal, so I guess this is a typo.

So instead of

```
new Minor(12052008, 14, 5,5, true)
```

use

```
new Minor(12052008, 14, 5.5, true)
```

Furthermore, your `print` method takes no argument, but you are trying to call it with one, and from a static context, both won't work.

Instead of

```
print(minor1);
```

use

```
minor1.print();
```

Comment: I fixed the typo and it still doesn't work. Why? Cab you help me?

Comment: @MohammadKherfan check the edit to my question.

Comment: also how do I close the question my code worked